# Create an "add-player" view - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I'm creating a game where the player has the possibility to add several players on a view controller :

[image]

Actually, I can add a new player and remove it :

[image]

The problem appears when I remove a player :

[image]

I want player 2 and player 3 goes below the textField "Name when I remove a player. How can I do this ?

ViewDidLoad :

```
// MARK: ADD BUTTON

    let addButtonSize = CGSize(width: topPartSize.height, height: topPartSize.height)

    let addButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: enterPlayerPartSize.width - addButtonSize.width, y: 0, width: addButtonSize.width, height: addButtonSize.height))
    addButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(addButtonSize.height / 2)
    addButton.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Plus), forState: .Normal)
    addButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    addButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5), forState: .Highlighted)
    addButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    addButton.layer.zPosition = 3
    addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayersViewController.addPlayer(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    enterPlayerPart.addSubview(addButton)

    // MARK: TEXT FIELD

    let textFieldSize = CGSize(width: enterPlayerPartSize.width - playerIconSize.width - addButtonSize.width, height: enterPlayerPartSize.height)

    textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: playerIconSize.width, y: 0, width: textFieldSize.width, height: textFieldSize.height))
    textField.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: textFieldSize.height / 2)
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Name", attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5)])
    textField.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done
    textField.delegate = self
    enterPlayerPart.addSubview(textField)
```

Functions :

```
// MARK: ADD PLAYER - FUNCTION

func addPlayer(sender: UIButton) {

    if textField.text == nil || textField.text == "" {

        print("Enter player name")

    } else {

        createNewPlayer(textField.text!)

    }

}


// MARK: CREATE NEW PLAYER - FUNCTION

func createNewPlayer(playerName: String) {

    let playerPartSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight * 0.1)

    let playerPart = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: playerPartSize.height * CGFloat(playersCount), width: playerPartSize.width, height: playerPartSize.height))
    scrollView.addSubview(playerPart)

    // PLAYER ICON

    let playerIconSize = CGSize(width: playerPartSize.height, height: playerPartSize.height)

    let playerIcon = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: playerIconSize.width, height: playerIconSize.height))
    playerIcon.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(topPartSize.height / 2)
    playerIcon.text = String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.User)
    playerIcon.textAlignment = .Center
    playerIcon.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    playerPart.addSubview(playerIcon)

    // REMOVE BUTTON

    let removeButtonSize = playerIconSize

    let removeButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: playerPartSize.width - removeButtonSize.width, y: 0, width: playerIconSize.width, height: playerIconSize.height))
    removeButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.fontAwesomeOfSize(removeButtonSize.height / 2)
    removeButton.setTitle(String.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Trash), forState: .Normal)
    removeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    removeButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 0.5), forState: .Highlighted)
    removeButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
    removeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayersViewController.removePlayer(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    playerPart.addSubview(removeButton)

    // PLAYER NAME

    let playerNameSize = CGSize(width: playerPartSize.width - playerIconSize.width - removeButtonSize.width, height: playerPartSize.height)

    let playerNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: playerIconSize.width, y: 0, width: playerNameSize.width, height: playerNameSize.height))
    playerNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: playerNameSize.height / 2)
    playerNameLabel.text = playerName
    playerNameLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    playerNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    playerPart.addSubview(playerNameLabel)

    // BOTTOM LINE

    let bottomLineHeight = playerPartSize.height / 50

    let bottomLine = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: playerPartSize.height - bottomLineHeight, width: playerPartSize.width, height: bottomLineHeight))
    bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexColor: 0x1B1B1B)
    playerPart.addSubview(bottomLine)

    // PLAYERS COUNT ++

    playersCount += 1

}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You should seriously consider using a `UITableView`! And the interface builder! And autolayout!

Comment: Yes I searched how to integrate it but it does not work, I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to perform it :

1. You seem using reusable components, so you should have a look on UITableView / UICollectionView. It will manage memory usage, and components layout
2. If you dont want to migrate to theses components, it recommend you to store all your player views in an array, and relayout them after an add/remove operation

something like :

```
var players : [UIView] = []
func createNewPlayer(playerName: String) {
   //Do your stuff here
    players.append(newCreatedPalyerView)
    layout()
}

func layout() {

   var yPosition = 0
  for view in players {
      view.frame.origin.y = yPosition
      yPosition += view.frame.size.height

  }
}

func removePlayer(player : UIView) {
    self.players.remove(player)
    self.layout()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the error `Value of type '[UIView]' has no member 'remove'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage your scenario something like below :

First take all the `UI` of one player in one `UIView`. So you should have all your one player's stuff(playername label, remove button etc) in one view. (i think you have it in `playerPart` - that`s cool)

Now you are adding that `playerPart` directly in `scrollview` i think, If it is like that then you should not do like this. You should have one `UIView` of same size of `scrollview` in `scrollview`(same as content size of scrollview) and you should add `playerPart` to that view.

Now you can get all subviews of that view in array something like :

```
   NSArray *viewArr = [tempView subviews];
```

Assume `tempView` is vied over scrollview as i have mentioned above,

you can get subview of scrollview also by calling same method.

Now for example you have four player(four view) in view (temp view or scrollview if tempview is not added on it) and you click remove on player 3 then you can get index of that object from that view array. for example,

you have array of total view which you have get from

```
   NSArray *viewArr = [tempView subviews];
```

then you can get index of player3 i.e view3 like,

```
  int index = [viewArr indexOfObject:player3];
```

now make one method or function which is called after every removed call and pass that index as parameter in that method.

In that method take one for loop, which start from this index and run till last object (view) of this viewArr. `Decrease y of every coming view in this for loop` so your all view which was belowed removed view will goes up.

Here is one my method i was using in my one project to remove view and manage other accordingly :

```
  #pragma mark UpdateFrameOfViews
-(void)updateFrameOfViewWithTag : (int) myTag increament : (CGFloat)increament fromIndex : (int)index{


CustomSubClassView *tempView = [self.view viewWithTag:myTag];
UIScrollView *tempScroll = (UIScrollView*)[tempView superview];
NSArray *subViews = [tempView subviews];
BOOL status = NO;

for (int i = index; i <= subViews.count; i++) {

    if (i < subViews.count) {

        UIView *tempView1 = [subViews objectAtIndex:i];

        CGFloat newY = tempView1.frame.origin.y + increament;

        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(tempView1.frame.origin.x, newY, tempView1.frame.size.width, tempView1.frame.size.height);

        tempView1.frame = newFrame;
        status = YES;

    }
    if (index == subViews.count && i == subViews.count) {

 //            UIView *tempView1 = [subViews lastObject];
 //            
 //            CGFloat newY = tempView1.frame.origin.y + increament;
 //            
//            CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(tempView1.frame.origin.x, newY, tempView1.frame.size.width, tempView1.frame.size.height);
 //            
//            tempView1.frame = newFrame;

        status = YES;
    }

  //  tempView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];




}
if (status) {

    CGRect containerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, tempView.frame.size.height+increament);

    tempView.frame = containerFrame;
    tempScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(tempView.frame.size.width, tempView.frame.size.height);

   }


 }
```

This method is for reference just, because here scenario is little bit different.

My code is in objective and is for reference only convert in swift required!!

This was how you manage it!!

**Suggestion : it is better to use `UITableView` in your case!!!**

Hope this will help :)